# How to search a data redis hash without key

Tags: redis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEfzY.jpg)
I shared the image of the doubt. Please help me out to search the redis key from the field value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the RediSearch module for Redis?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the redisearch module and i only found for full text search. 
I can't compare it with numeric values . Please help me , I am new to Redis.

Comment: Don't post a question as an image, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For numeric filter in RediSearch please see: https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Query_Syntax/#numeric_filters_in_query

Answer (score 0):

For raw Redis solution, it is hard to make a range query with Hash/String data  structure.

A general solution is using an extra zset to store the numeric value as score and id as value. When doing a range query, first query from zset to get all possible ids, and then query back to your hash to get all data.